# Apache problems on AWS EC2 - URL path interpreted as sub-directory

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, yii, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to migrate a website from cPanel based hosting to AWS EC2 and am having problems with URL Paths being interpreted as sub-directories.

for example www.mysite.com/page/page-name is giving the error in the apache error log /var/www/html/page/page-name not found.

I've hardly changed the Apache config file at all.
As you can see above the site is running in /var/www/http, I'm not using any vhosts

The site is written using the Yii framework on PHP
The home page display OK, so php and Yii are OK.

I have the normal htaccess file in the web root:-

```
RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteBase /

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and in Yii configuration I'm using the usual urlManager config:

```
'urlFormat' => 'path',
'showScriptName' => false,
```

Is there something I should be adding to httpd.conf?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to enable AllowOverrides in order for your .htaccess to take effect.

Look in your httpd.conf file and find the following line

```
AllowOverride None
```

Change this to

```
AllowOverride All
```

There may be more than one AllowOverride directive. The one you want to change is the one within the Directory stanza for /var/www/html.